# In Browser, Does the UI thread have its own ui queue whose queue member is dom update operation(just like ‘dom.style.color = ‘#fff’’) only?

Tags: javascript, browser, ui-thread, event-loop

I saw a demo which talks about how the javascript runtime in browser works. It put the dom update operation  in message queue which is processed by the js thread. But in my understanding, the dom update operation  is processed by the UI thread, not by the js thread. Is there any problem in the demo? Does the UI thread have its own ui queue whose queue member is dom update operation only?
I hope someone can give me more detail about the interaction between the js thread and ui thread, thank you. The demo code is as follows:

```
(function() {
    var ele = document.querySelector(‘#ele’);
    ele.style.color = ‘#fff;
  // will run 1 minutes
  longCalc();
})()
```

Comment: The DOM update is not processed by the UI thread no. All DOM operations are treated synchronously during the js execution. There is the special case of the reflow operation, which is often triggered only after all the js and DOM operations have been executed, but which can also be forced during script execution with e.g `element.offsetTop`. The UI thread would be responsible for the repaint operation. I have no official source, but this is implementation dependent. E.g, in chrome, if you do `alert` (an js thread blocking action), the page won't be repainted, but in FF it will be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does touching the DOM trigger a reflow and repaint even if nothing changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453465/does-touching-the-dom-trigger-a-reflow-and-repaint-even-if-nothing-changes)